# Should I correct odds ratios for multiple testing and if yes, how?

Tags: r, categorical-data, multiple-comparisons, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

I did I fisher test (2x3 table) and after a significant result I performed three separate fisher tests for the possible comparisions. I corrected the p-values for multiple comparisons, but in addition I would like to report odds ratios and I wonder if I should correct them as well and if yes, how I could do this.